# Using Binding converter to display and update a property in silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, mvvm

I am using a converter class to display a property called noofweeks based on normal working hours(40), so for example if the value stored in database is 40 I am displaying 1 in the datagrid column, if it is 80 I am displaying 2, here is my XAML and converter code

```
<sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn Width="*"  CanUserReorder="False" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource DataGridBaseHeaderStyle}" Header="FTE">
                <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <TextBlock  Text="{Binding Hours, Converter={StaticResource FTEConverter}}"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="4,2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"></TextBlock>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Hours,Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource FTEConverter}}"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="4,2" 
                                         MaxLength="50" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
                        </TextBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>

 public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
      {
          if (value == null)
              return false;
          else
          {
              // Assumes a RowType has been passed as the bound value
              Double Hours= (Double)value;
                       return Math.Round(Hours/40,0);
              }
          }
```

so the Data Grid  for UserID 1 and 2 where no of hours in database are 80 and 120 respectively looks like

```
 UserID  NoOfWeeks        StandardHours(not visible to user)   
   1        2                  80
   2        3                  120
```

This is working fine as expected, now I want to update the hours in the database based on NoOfWeeks modifed by the user.

for example in the above table if user with UserID updates the NoOfWeeks to 4 I want to save the hours as 160 (4 *40).

UserID  NoOfWeeks        StandardHours(not visible to user)
   1        4                  160
   2        3                  120
I am getting a bit confused here to how do I update the property?

Comment: How have you implemented the ConvertBack method of IValueConverter?

Comment: Funny that you mentioned it because I was just having a look at it. Normally for most of the converters I dont need to implement the convertback method as the binding is one way and I just return null  for this one I think I'll have to implement the Convertback method. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who are new to MVVM and Converters, what I did is use the ConvertBack method to convert user input to Hours

```
 public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
      {
           if (value == null)
              return false;
          else
          {
              // Assumes a RowType has been passed as the bound value
              string val = (string)value;
              double doubleValue = double.TryParse(val, out doubleValue) ? doubleValue : 0;
              return doubleValue * 40;
              }
          }
      }
```

One thing to note is that if the user enters text or anything besides numbers I am converting the value to 0. This might not suit your requirements and you can use IDataErrorInfo in your property setters to stop and notify users from entering values that are not allowed.